# Проверить наличие скобок

Tags: python

Простой символьный граф:

```
class Base:

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Add(self, other)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Mul(self, other)


class Binary:

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b


class Const(Base):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def eval(self):
        return self.value

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)


class Add(Base, Binary):

    def eval(self):
        return self.a.eval() + self.b.eval()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s + %s' % (self.a, self.b)


class Mul(Base, Binary):

    def eval(self):
        return self.a.eval() * self.b.eval()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s * %s' % (self.a, self.b)


a = Const(2)
b = Const(3)

fn = a + b * a + b + a
print(fn)
```

В зависимости от задачи скобки в выражениях могут стоять в разных местах:

```
fn = a + b * (a + b * a)
print(fn) # a + b * a + b * a
fn2 = (a + b * a + b) * a
print(fn2) # a + b * a + b * a
```

Как показано выше вывод в оболочку не соответствует выражению, так как в `__str__()` нет соответствующего условия, но считает понятное дело все правильно:

```
fn.eval()  # 26
fn2.eval() # 22
```

Вопрос, как проверить наличие скобок что бы в зависимости от этого обозначить их в `__str__()`, `__repr__()`?

```
def __str__(self):
    Если есть скобки то:
        return ('%s) * %s' % (self.a, self.b)
    return '%s * %s' % (self.a, self.b)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я бы немного переделал саму иерархию классов (например, сделал бы класс `Op` и от него бы наследовал `Binary`, `Unary`, `Ternary` и так далее, а также сделал бы абстрактный метод `eval`), но если опираться на представленные в вопросе классы, то у меня мысль дополнить класс `Binary` вот так:

```
class Binary:
    priority = 0
    op = ''

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (
            # Длинную строчку можно переписать покрасивее, но мне лень
            ('(%s)' % self.a) if isinstance(self.a, Binary) and self.a.priority < self.priority else self.a,
            self.op,
            ('(%s)' % self.b) if isinstance(self.b, Binary) and self.b.priority < self.priority else self.b,
        )
```

Суть проста: если приоритет вложенных операторов ниже текущего приоритета, то заворачиваем в скобки. (Вариантов реализации `__str__` масса разных по длине и красоте, можно переписать на свой вкус)

Ну а классы-потомки получаются совсем простые. Я для наглядности добавлю ещё вычитание, у которого одинаковый со сложением приоритет (в `class Base` соответственно дописывается `def __sub__`):

```
class Add(Base, Binary):
    priority = 1
    op = '+'
    def eval(self):
        return self.a.eval() + self.b.eval()


class Sub(Base, Binary):
    priority = 1
    op = '-'
    def eval(self):
        return self.a.eval() - self.b.eval()


class Mul(Base, Binary):
    priority = 2
    op = '*'
    def eval(self):
        return self.a.eval() * self.b.eval()
```

Для них даже `__str__` реализовывать не надо (но если очень хочется, то можно, конечно).

И всё, это отлично работает:

```
a = Const(2)
b = Const(3)

fn = a + b * (a + b * a)
print(fn)  # → 2 + 3 * (2 + 3 * 2)
print(fn.eval())  # → 26

fn = (a + b * a + b) * a
print(fn)  # → (2 + 3 * 2 + 3) * 2
print(fn.eval())  # → 22

# Пример с одинаковым приоритетом разных операторов: скобок нет
fn = a + b * a - b + a
print(fn)  # → 2 + 3 * 2 - 3 + 2
print(fn.eval())  # → 7
```

Comment: Отличное решение, спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена, вдруг кому будет полезно на примере класса `Mul` парочка условий в `__str__` (условий на деле на много больше, привел пару для того что бы отобразить суть решения):

```
class Mul(Base, Binary):

    def eval(self):
        return self.a.eval() * self.b.eval()

    def __str__(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'a') and self.a.__class__.__name__ == 'Add':
            return '(%s) * %s' % (self.a, self.b)
        elif hasattr(self, 'b') and self.b.__class__.__name__ == 'Add':
            return '%s * (%s)' % (self.a, self.b)
        return '%s * %s' % (self.a, self.b)
```

Теперь отображение в оболочке корректно:

```
fn = (a + a) * a
print(fn) # (a + a) * a
```

Comment: Думаю, вместо захардкоженной проверки на Add можно выдать каждому оператору номер приоритета (больше число - больше приоритет, ну или наоборот) и с помощью сравнения приоритетов решать, добавлять скобки или нет

Comment: @andreymal спасибо за идею, действительно с приоритетом операций гораздо лучше!